# Did the Kryptonian Codex survive Superman's death and resurrection?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

As shown in *Man of Steel*, the Codex is "digitally preserved and infused" into Superman's blood cells by his father, but cells and DNA die and degrade quite quickly upon death, therefore how could the (digital) imprint possibly survive the loss of its storage?

But we do also see that some type of energy remained in or around Superman's corpse when Lois' handful of dirt hovers over his coffin (in the same manner as when Superman's about to take flight), so I suppose it's possible it remained intact. Has the Codex ever been discuss or touched on after Superman's resurrection?

Comment: Kryptonian cells don't degrade on Earth. It's the reason they can't autopsy Zod. His skin and cells are still impermeable after death

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks.. this is true isn't it. Soo, it's left to us to assume the digital Codex survives? (I'm kind of hung up on digital part too and "remaining energy" to maintain the copy/imprint. They did have to "jumpstart" him with energy for the resurrection) Do you happen to know it's ever been clarified, after the Zod storyline? (Movie or comic) Thnx again

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. It's kinda a one'n'done plot point that was invented for that film, then never discussed again.

Comment: I see..Makes sense I guess (if not a little disappointing lol) It's still a really intriguing part of the storyline to me, and something that seems could've definitely been expanded on, imo.. i.e  Luther somehow extracts a Kryptonian warrior army directly from Superman or something to that nature.. again just my op